is there any way to tell which came first - high or low in a candle in pinescript?
is there any way to tell which came first - high or low in a candle in pinescript
I need a script that can tell me in a 15m candle what is the last high or low without seeing if the candle is green or red.
is there a way to know the time of high and low to compare it afterwards ?

There is no 100% accurate way to do this.
You can use request.security_lower_tf() to get data from lower timeframes such as 1-minute or seconds. It will return an array so you can see which one comes first.

Can you give me any example please ?
